# TypeScript: Tagged Template Literals shows Error

Tags: javascript, typescript, template-literals

I am trying to use [tagged template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) of ES5 with typescript but it seems like type script does not have full support for it. I have following piece of code.

```
class TemplateLiterals { 
    age: number = 24;
    name: 'Luke Skywalker'
    private tag(strings: string[], personExp, ageExp) :string{
        var str0 = strings[0]; // "that "
        var str1 = strings[1]; // " is a "
        var ageStr;
        if (ageExp > 99) {
            ageStr = 'centenarian';
        } else {
            ageStr = 'youngster';
        }
        return str0 + personExp + str1 + ageStr;
    }
    toString() {
        return this.tag `that ${ this.name } is a ${ this.age }`;
    }
}
```

In `toString` method, typescript is showing me following error.

```
Argument of type 'TemplateStringsArray' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string[]'.
Property 'push' is missing in type 'TemplateStringsArray'.
```

I don't know why it's showing me this error. As per the mozilla's doc "The first argument of a tag function contains an array of string values." So it should accept the array of string. But the actual expectation is `TemplateStringsArray`. not sure how and when the `interface` `TemplateSringsArray` is being defined. Currently I am using `TemplateSringsArray` type to avoid this error. Can anyone please explain whats happening. Thanks. Here's the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%0D%0Aclass%20TemplateLiterals%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20age%3A%20number%20%3D%2024%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'Luke%20Skywalker'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20tag(strings%3A%20string%5B%5D%2C%20personExp%2C%20ageExp)%20%3Astring%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20str0%20%3D%20strings%5B0%5D%3B%20%2F%2F%20%22that%20%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20str1%20%3D%20strings%5B1%5D%3B%20%2F%2F%20%22%20is%20a%20%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20ageStr%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(ageExp%20%3E%2099)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ageStr%20%3D%20'centenarian'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ageStr%20%3D%20'youngster'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20str0%20%2B%20personExp%20%2B%20str1%20%2B%20ageStr%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20toString()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.tag%20%60that%20%24%7B%20this.name%20%7D%20is%20a%20%24%7B%20this.age%20%7D%60%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After exploring more, I finally found explanations in the [change log](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#templatestringsarray-is-now-immutable). Hope it will help someone. It says

> ES2015 tagged templates always pass their tag an immutable array-like
>   object that has a property called raw (which is also immutable).
>   TypeScript names this object the TemplateStringsArray.
>
> Conveniently, TemplateStringsArray was assignable to an Array,
>   so it's possible users took advantage of this to use a shorter type
>   for their tag parameters:

```
function myTemplateTag(strs: string[]) {
    // ... 
}
```

> However, in TypeScript 2.0, the language now supports the readonly modifier and 
>   can express that these objects are immutable. As
>   a result, TemplateStringsArray has also been made immutable, and is no
>   longer assignable to string[].

Recommendation:

Use `TemplateStringsArray` explicitly (or use `ReadonlyArray<string>`).

Comment: This is only useful if you have control over the function.

Answer (score 2):

I also can not find any documentation about `TemplateStringsArray` - but if you just ignore the error by changing the parameter to `TemplateStringsArray` rather than `string[]` (and fix a bug with the name member) it seems to work OK

```
class TemplateLiterals { 
    age: number = 24;
    name: string = 'Luke Skywalker'
    private tag(strings: TemplateStringsArray, personExp, ageExp) :string{
        var str0 = strings[0]; // "that "
        var str1 = strings[1]; // " is a "
        var ageStr;
        if (ageExp > 99) {
            ageStr = 'centenarian';
        } else {
            ageStr = 'youngster';
        }
        return str0 + personExp + str1 + ageStr;
    }
    toString() {
        return this.tag `that ${ this.name } is a ${ this.age }`;
    }
}

var luke: TemplateLiterals = new TemplateLiterals()
console.log(luke.toString())
```

Comment: `Currently I am using TemplateSringsArray type to avoid this error.`

Answer (score 1):

The above answer didn't work for me, perhaps the requirement has changed as of now (December 2021).

But I was able to resolve my issue using `ReadonlyArray<string>` instead of `string[]`.

Here is my sample function in case this helps someone.

```
function myTemplateTag(strs: ReadonlyArray<string>) {
  // Do something.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Angular's `$localize` function. My problem was that I used it the wrong way:

```
// ERROR:
const translated = $localize(`Something to translate!`);
// WORKS, remove the parentheses:
const translated = $localize`Something to translate!`;
```

Hope that saves somebody some minutes :D